Unable to access SQL Server due to a Trigger execution
-- Create a table to store login audit information
CREATE TABLE dbo.UserLoginAudit 
(
    AuditID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LoginName NVARCHAR(100),
    LoginTime DATETIME
);

-- Create a server-level DDL trigger to capture logins
CREATE TRIGGER tr_UserLoginAudit
ON ALL SERVER
FOR LOGON
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LoginName NVARCHAR(100);
    SET @LoginName = ORIGINAL_LOGIN();

My goal with the above script was to capture SQL logins and store in a table. Immediately after running the above script, I did not have access again to the SQL Instance where the script got executed, and I have been trying to resolve this issue to no avail, keep getting this error:

TITLE: Connect to Server
Cannot connect to TEST.
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
Logon failed for login 'username' due to trigger execution.
Changed database context to 'master'.
Changed language setting to us_english. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 17892)

Please I need help on how to resolve this issue. Thank you.
I tried researching online to search for a solution to this issue but still haven't been able to solve it

I'm not sure how hard you researched, but check this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-17892-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16 If you're already logged on, drop the trigger, and if you aren't, you need to login as DAC (see scenario 2 in the link) and then drop the trigger

That trigger isn't  complete either, it's just 2 statements, and I'm doubtful those would cause a failure; it's just a variable declaration and assignment.

"My goal with the above script was to capture SQL logins and store in a table." Why use a table? SQL Server has this feature built in, you just need to enable the server to log successful logins.
